# I need to SELECT from a table based on attributes not being present in another table

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I have the following tables:

```
   VENDOR:          PRODUCT:           ITEM:             STORE:
-  VENDOR_ID     -  PRODUCT_ID      -  ITEM_ID        -  STORE_ID
-  VENDOR_NAME   -  PRODUCT_DESC    -  STORE_ID       -  STORE_NAME
                 -  VENDOR_ID       -  PRODUCT_ID     -  STORE_LOCATION
                                    -  ITEM_PRICE
```

The ITEM table is essentially the inventory of the stores, telling which products each store has in stock. I want to make a list of all the vendors who don't provide any products to any of the stores in the database.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR.VENDOR_NAME AS VENDORNAME
FROM VENDOR, PRODUCT, ITEM, STORE
WHERE NOT VENDOR.VENDOR_ID = PRODUCT.VENDOR_ID
AND NOT PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ITEM.PRODUCT_ID
AND NOT ITEM.STORE_ID = STORE.STORE_ID;
```

Right now, it returns all the vendor names. Do you have any ideas that would make it return only the vendors whose products are not in any of the stores? Thanks.

Comment: Your task description is not clear. You may want to post a sample data and the expected result. Also indicate what RDBMS (SQL *flavor*) you use.

Answer (score 0):

Since item shows what products are in each store for each vendor if a product is not in the item table then it is one you want.  A left join will leave those null.  Just check for those items which are null. Like this:

```
select *
from vendor v
join product p on v.vendor_id = p.product_id
left join item i on p.product_id = i.product_id
where i.product_id is null
```

OR

Look for all products which are not in the item table.  This ignores the vendor table:

```
select *
from product p
where product_id not in (select product_id from item)
```

Now find those vendors

```
select * 
from vendor
where vendor_id in
(
   select vendor_id 
   from product p
   where product_id not in (select product_id from item)
)
```

Both of these answers are logically the same, the first uses joins, the 2nd sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT MAX(v.VENDOR_NAME) AS VENDORNAME
FROM VENDOR v
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT p ON v.endor_id = p_vendor_id
LEFT JOIN ITEM i ON p_product_id = i.product_id
GROUP BY v.vendor_id
HAVING COUNT(i.item_id) = 0;
```

`STORE` table is not needed for such query.

Comment: hmmm, are you sure about the left join to product?  I'd expect that to be an inner join.

Comment: @Hogan - Wouldn't inner join filter out all vendors without products to offer?

Comment: True, this is a requirements question, I figured the OP would not be interested in that group... but the OP could be, it is not clear.